# Vue - Nested Click Event Bubbling Issue

Tags: vue.js, click, vuejs2

I have a menu button with a click event in Vue.  When the button is clicked, it's supposed to activate the menu itself.  This is the parent element which when clicked activates the menu (the toggleMenu function makes `menuIsActive` true).  This part works fine:

```
<div class="navbar-item has-dropdown @click="toggleMenu">
  <div class="navbar-link"></div>
  <app-navmenu :class="{'is-active': menuIsActive}"/>
</div>
```

And this is the `app-navmenu` component that gets rendered:

```
<div class="navbar-dropdown" @click.stop>
  <div class="container is-fluid">
    <div class="column">
      <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
      <router-link class="navbar-item" :to="route" exact>
        <div class="navbar-content">
          <p class="has-text-info">info</p>
          <small>meta info</small>
        </div>
      </router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem I am running into is that I don't want the menu to disappear when I click on the actual `navbar-dropdown` div element, hence why I have a `@click.stop`.  However, I do want the menu to disappear when I click on a `router-link` element, but since I have `@click.stop` in the `navbar-dropdown` element, the menu persists.  If I don't have a `@click.stop` event on the `navbar-dropdown` element, then the menu disappears as soon as the `navbar-dropdown` element is clicked on, which I don't want.

How can I have the menu persist when clicking on the dropdown body, but also have it disappear when I click on a router-link?  I've tried other click methods like `.self` and `.prevent`, but those don't seem to do what I need.

Comment: I'mexactly not sure, can you explain by listing? on click dropdown, you want menu to appear and on click of router-link you want menu to disappear?

Comment: The default behavior is that once the menu is activated, if I click on a link OR on the body of the menu, it disappears.  I want the menu to persist if I click on the body, but I want it to disappear if I click on a link.

Comment: what happens if you put the .stop on the click event? <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown @click.stop="toggleMenu">

Comment: The default behavior - the menu will disappear if I click on the body OR on a link within the menu.

Comment: Sorry, still not getting to the point... can you visualize?

Comment: Put a click handler on the router-link element that `$emit`s an event and have the parent handle that.

Comment: Are click functions allowed on `<router-link/>` elements?  I am finding that if i put a click function in one of the children of the `<router-link/>` elements, I can get it to work.  But if I put it directly in the `<router-link/>` element, the click function isn't even registered.  I even tried using .prevent.

Comment: That may be. Wrap the `<router-link>` in a `<div>` and put the handler on that. Or maybe on the `<div>` inside the `<router-link>`.

Comment: Thanks Roy - that's what I did.  I posted an answer.

Comment: Actually - per the comments below, I forgot all about the requirement for using `.native` on elements like router-links.  So no need for the wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

I am exactly not sure with your requirement, but following your comment, you can use something like this:

This will even push to the router link:

```
<router-link class="navbar-item" :to="route" exact 
 @click.native.prevent="callYourMethod">
```

This will prevent to go to the router link:

```
<router-link class="navbar-item" :to="route" exact 
 @click.native.prevent="callYourMethod" event="">
```

Comment: Yep - I just read the docs and forgot all about `.native`.  Thanks for the assist.

Comment: Glad this helped. Please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing to fix my issue.  First, I moved the click function in the parent to one of its children:

```
<div class="navbar-item has-dropdown">
  <div class="navbar-link" @click="toggleMenu"></div>
  <app-navmenu :class="{'is-active': menuIsActive}"/>
</div>
```

This lets the body of the menu stay active even when I click on the body without having to use a `@click.stop`.  Then in the menu itself, I did this so that links will close the menu:

```
<div class="navbar-dropdown" @click.stop>
  <div class="container is-fluid">
    <div class="column">
      <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
      <div @click="toggleMenu">
        <router-link class="navbar-item" :to="route" exact>
          <div class="navbar-content">
            <p class="has-text-info">info</p>
            <small>meta info</small>
          </div>
        </router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

One strange behavior I noticed is that if I put the `@click="toggleMenu"` function in the `<router-link/>` element itself, it doesn't get called on, even if I use `.prevent`.  Hence the need for the div wrapper around the router-link element.

Comment: I forgot that `@click.native` is required on the `<router-link/>` element.  So no need for wrapper.